# Is it safe to consume a C library built with older version of Xcode?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, llvm, llvm-clang

We build and deploy a dynamic framework targeting iOS that contains Objective-c code. It consumes a "core" (our terminology) static library that contains C/C++ code. But we only consume it through the C interfaces. We do not have any Objective-C++ that we use to consume any of the internal C++ interfaces, and none of the C++ API is exposed through headers. It's all straight Objective-C in our framework consuming and linking in a static library through pure C headers and a C interface.

We are wondering if it is safe to consume the "core" static library if we build it with an older version of Xcode (LLVM). And if so, is it safe even for major version differences of compiler or minor only?

thanks

Comment: How do you personally define "safe" in the context of your question?

Comment: If the lib is not too complex why don't you just include the source .c and .h files in your project and compile it using the 'latest' compiler that you also use to compile your framework?

Comment: @ChuckWolber - safe would mean not crashing and no unexpected behavior that wouldn't normally occur, but does because of the differences in compilers.

Comment: @skaak, it's a fair question. One of the reasons is that we have multiple teams that depend on that library. Another reason is that it's a different team that works on that library, and the team that consumes it, doesn't need to be bothered by compiling it every time we make a change.

Comment: Ok - fwiw I have one of those. Library with a few C files. Development and testing does not even happen in Xcode or llvm, but the source files are included as part of the iOS Objective-C project and compiled along with it and it works great. Since it is pretty standard C the compiler really does not matter and it helps that it is kept sort of close to home.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find an authoritative source, so I won't post an answer, but I would say it's highly likely to work, although it probably depends on *how* old of a compiler you're talking about. All you really need here is C ABI stability, and I would be shocked to see that break especially between just minor version bumps of Xcode. However, the **most safe and reliable** thing you could do would be to include the sources in your project. *"compiling it every time we make a change"* – isn't the build product being cached so you only build it when it actually changes?

Comment: "compiling it every time we make a change" is an exaggeration, my apologies. The C library is a very large codebase and takes about 20 minutes to compile clean per architecture on a modern pro laptop. The objective-c abstraction above that library takes about a minute. We have > 100 developers working on the C library everyday, so it changes quite a bit.  It's not really feasible to pull the source into our Xcode project.